# Calculate area & perimeter of a geojson feature of GeojsonLayer in deck.gl

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, mapbox, deck.gl

I am using deck.gl to render a geojsonlayer using their geojsonlayer function, where the source of data is a geojson file.

Now I want display an infowindow to show area & perimeter of each feature, when clicked on them on the map. I have managed to fetch the properties object of a particular feature and show its reverse geocode address and display them in the infoWindow (pic below),
[image]

which also gives me access to the geofence coordinates of that particular feature. But I am not able to find any function from the documentation that allows us to calculate the area. Is there anything I missed here? Or Do I have to calculate it manually based on cartesian space and spheroid?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found turf.js that does the job for calculating area and perimeter of a geojson feature.

Comment: I do not see in the documentation how to calculate the perimeter, did you find any examples of how to do this?

Comment: https://turfjs.org/docs/#length @KarlsMaranjs you can use this function to calculate length/perimeter of any geojson feature, be it polyline, polygon or multipolygon